# Múltiplos Prototypes

Tags: javascript, node.js, protótipo

Gostaria de saber como adicionar um prototype para uma função que já está instanciada em um prototype. Exemplo abaixo:

app.js

```
'use strict';

function NivFire(){
    this.db = "", this.admin = "", this.reference;
}

NivFire.prototype = {
    Fire : function(credential,url){},
    Ref : function(ref){ }
};

NivFire.prototype.Ref.prototype = {
    Set: (args) => {},
    Push: (args) => {}
};

module.exports = NivFire;
```

main.js

```
var NivFire = require("./app.js");
var nivfire = new NivFire();
nivfire.Fire( require('./nivellirfirebase.json'), "https://nivellir-97d87.firebaseio.com" );

nivfire.Ref("users").Set({
  name : "User1"
});
```

Quando esse código é executado, retorna o TypeError: Cannot read property 'Set' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) para definir uma nova propriedade diretamente em um objeto, ou modificar uma propriedade já existente em um objeto. Para evitar repetições de código e facilitar a manutenção, crie um novo modulo, aqui dou o nome do arquivo como *definePropriedade.js*

```
let config = {
  writable: false,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
};

const definePropriedade = (obj, nome, valor) => {
  config.value = valor;
  Object.defineProperty(obj, nome, config);
}

module.exports = definePropriedade;
```

depois importe no arquivo que será utilizado, no caso *app.js*

```
let definePropriedade = require('./definePropriedade.js');
```

agora basta chamar o método informando o protótipo:

```
// Define a propriedade: "Fire"
definePropriedade(NivFire.prototype, 'Fire', (credential,url) => {
  console.log(credential, url);
});
```

quando for definir a propriedade de uma propriedade, basta chamar o método novamente dentro dele mesmo e informar o valor `this` como protótipo:

```
// Define a propriedade: "Ref"
definePropriedade(NivFire.prototype, 'Ref', (ref) => {
  console.log(`Usando Ref: ${ref}`);
  // Define a propriedade: "Set"
  definePropriedade(this, 'Set', (args) => {
    console.log(`Usando Set: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
  });
  // Define a propriedade: "Push"
  definePropriedade(this, 'Push', (args) => {
    console.log(`Usando Push: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
  });
  // Para que funcione "Ref('users').Set({ name : 'User1' })"
  // deve retornar o objeto
  return this;
});
```

Veja [funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DemandingHonorableMegahertz)

#### Referência

- [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)